# Set file as executable from Live CD

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, live-cd, unetbootin

I'm writing this from Live CD 12.04. I downloaded Ubuntu 13.04 and Unetbootin on my external hard drive, now I'm trying to make bootable usb drive so I can install Ubuntu 13.04 but I can't open Unetbootin because I can't set it as executable. Can someone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

**You have best solution with you**

Follow these step to make **Ubuntu 13.04** bootable USB:

- Since you are using Ubuntu 12.04, open `Startup Disk Creator` (search in dash)
- In first option `Source disc image:( .iso or CD)` select your Ubuntu 13.04. Browse it by clicking <kbd>Other..</kbd> button.
- On second option`Disk to use:` select your `USB drive`, if inserted it would b automatically selected. You may have to `Erase` it before making bootable. Click <kbd>Erase Disk</kbd> button to erase it enable button <kbd>Make Startup Disk</kbd>
- Then finall click <kbd>Make Startup Disk</kbd> to make your `USB Drive` Bootable.

[image]

- That all.. It would take some time around 3-5 minutes and will make your `USB` bootable..

Reply if you need further assistance..

Comment: Tried that but first it refuse to select .iso image on my hard drive, it just accepts the default one from Ubuntu 12.04, and second when I booted from flash drive I got some error, error started with Casper: and I don't remember the rest

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't get you.. If you have Ubuntu 13.04 iso file and a pen drive, this is the best way to make your pen drive bootable. It will never give you error like other s/w which are used to make USB bootable. It never fails me!!! Could you please elaborate your problem, or try it again.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Maybe I did something wrong while doing the process you described, but I installed Ubuntu 12.04 and then created bootable flash drive with 13.04 on it.

Comment: Did you use `Ubuntu 12.04` with `Bootable USB`? and were you trying to make it `Bootable USB` of `Ubuntu 13.04`?? :) I thought that you were using Live CD/DVD to boot `Ubuntu 12.04`. In that case obviously you'll need other `USB Drive`.. and change option from `Disk to Use:` option ;) If you don't have another `USB Drive` then yes you've to first install `Ubuntu 12.04` and using it you have to make `Ubuntu 13.04` bootable disk. :D That you did I think..

Comment: No, I had .iso image of 13.04 on my hard drive for media and stuff, then I used 12.04 Live CD (from CD not USB) and I tried to make 13.04 bootable flash drive

Comment: Yes, the same thing I was suggesting you! What was the problem..?It should have proceeded without any error.. I've made bootable USB many times using this way.. It is good to know that you solved your problem anyhow! :)